# currying multiple functions in parallel in F#

Tags: functional-programming, f#

I'm trying to learn F# at the moment and have come up on a problem I can't solve and can't find any answers for on google.

Initially I wanted a log function that would work like the printf family of functions whereby I could provide a format string and a number of arguments (statically checked) but which would add a little metadata before printing it out. With googling, I found this was possible using a function like the following:

```
let LogToConsole level (format:Printf.TextWriterFormat<'T>) =
    let extendedFormat = (Printf.TextWriterFormat<string->string->'T> ("%s %s: " + format.Value))
    let date = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"
    let lvl = string level
    printfn extendedFormat date lvl
```

having the `printfn` function as the last line of this function allows the varargs-like magic of the printf syntax whereby the partially-applied printfn method is returned to allow the caller to finish applying arguments.

However, if I have multiple such functions with the same signature, say `LogToConsole`, `LogToFile` and others, how could I write a function that would call them all keeping this partial-application magic?

Essential I'm looking for how I could implement a function `MultiLog`
that would allow me to call multiple printf-like functions from a single function call Such as in the ResultIWant function below:

```
type LogFunction<'T> = LogLevel -> Printf.TextWriterFormat<'T> -> 'T

let MultiLog<'T> (loggers:LogFunction<'T>[]) level (format:Printf.TextWriterFormat<'T>) :'T = 
    loggers
    |> Seq.map (fun f -> f level format)
    |> ?????????

let TheResultIWant =
    let MyLog = MultiLog [LogToConsole; LogToFile]
    MyLog INFO "Text written to %i outputs" 2
```

---

Perhaps the essence of this question can be caught more succintly: given a list of functions of the same signature how can I partially apply them all with the same arguments?

```
type ThreeArg = string -> int -> bool -> unit
let funcs: ThreeArg seq = [func1; func2; func3]

let MagicFunction = ?????

// I'd like this to be valid
let partiallyApplied = MagicFunction funcs "string"

// I'd also like this to be valid
let partiallyApplied = MagicFunction funcs "string" 255

// and this (fullyApplied will be `unit`)
let fullyApplied = MagicFunction funcs "string" 255 true
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the specific part of the question regarding string formatting, there is a useful function `Printf.kprintf` which lets you do what you need in a very simple way - the first parameter of the function is a continuation that gets called with the formatted string as an argument. In this continuation, you can just take the formatted string and write it to all the loggers you want. Here is a basic example:

```
let Loggers = [printfn "%s"]

let LogEverywhere level format =
    Printf.kprintf (fun s ->
      let date = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"
      let lvl = string level
      for logger in Loggers do logger (sprintf "%s %s %s" date lvl s)) format

LogEverywhere "BAD" "hi %d" 42
```

I don't think there is a nice and simple way to do what you wanted to do in the more general case - I suspect you might be able to use some reflection or static member constraints magic, but fortunately, you don't need to in this case!

Answer (score 0):

There is almost nothing to add to a perfect @TomasPetricek answer as he is basically a "semi-god" in F#. Another alternative, which comes to mind, is to use a computation expression (see, for example: https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/series/computation-expressions.html). When used properly it does look like magic :) However, I have a feeling that it is a little bit too heavy for the problem, which you described.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm not sure I see how computation expressions could be used in this scenario though. Could you provide an example? I understand that they allow you to modify a selection of operators and essentially wrap/unwrap/conditionally execute bits of the code but am not sufficiently familiar with them to understand how to really use them.

Comment: In a very simple terms, computation expression allows to "wrap" each action where they are applied into some standard action(s). I think that one of the examples in the reference talks that computation expression can be used to "log" actions without the user actually doing much about it. In your case you have multiple loggers, so, after extending the example, the user would not know that many loggers were applied. This is heavy, but works like magic. I read that reference several times before I could use it :(

Comment: Ah, yes I see. For implicitly logging off bindings, this would indeed be a viable option.